# My code with scrollview is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am using swift to get my scrollview going the structure of my elements is as shown[image]

The code that i am using in my view controller is

```
import UIKit

class scrollview: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scroller.userInteractionEnabled=true

        scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)
```

But i am not able to make my page scroll can anyone help me out with this am i missing any constrains or something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

In order for `UIScrollView` to scroll, the content size must be greater than its frame size. If, for example, you want to scroll vertically, it has to be true that scrollView.contentSize.height > scrollView.frame.size.height.

Answer (score 0):

scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(should be total width of the labels not scroll view width, should be total height of the labels not scrollview height)

contentsize should be greater than frame size for scrolling.